# Integral of 2-D Laplacian

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I am so confused on these integrals.

Here is the question.

**Problem**

$$G(x,y)=\ln(x^2+y^2)/2$$

Calculate the 2-D Laplacian $\Delta^2G$

For the interior $D$ of the circle $C$ of radius $a$ calculate $$\int\int\Delta^2GdA$$

My questions are, is the Laplacian a vector field or a scalar?  How do I set the integral up?

I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: The laplacian is noted $\Delta$ of maybe $\nabla^2$, unless you wanted to calculate the laplacian of the laplacian ?

Comment: I've seen the Laplacian denoted with the downward pointing triangle (del symbol?) but I wasn't sure what the command was in MathJax so I just used the capital delta.  So using my notation of capital delta the problem calls for integrating $\Delta^2G$.  Is that called the Laplacian or is that the Laplacian of the Laplacian? Your answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: $\nabla$ is the "del" operator, often called "nabla" (which is actually the name of the symbol), and $\Delta=\nabla^2$ is the laplacian. $\Delta^2$ would be the laplacian applied twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The laplacian operator defined on the scalar field gives a scalar. Here, it is defined as
$$\Delta G\left(x,y\right):=\partial_x^2G\left(x,y\right)+\partial_y^2G\left(x,y\right).$$
We compute
$$\partial_xG\left(x,y\right)
=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},$$
$$\partial_x^2G\left(x,y\right)
=\frac{y^2-x^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$$
and by as $x$ and $y$ plays the same role in the expression of $G$, we deduce that
$$\partial_y^2G\left(x,y\right)
=\frac{x^2-y^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}.$$
We then see that $\partial_x^2G\left(x,y\right)+\partial_y^2G\left(x,y\right)=0$ then the integral is zero. In fact, $G$ is **harmonic**, *i.e.* $\Delta G\equiv0$.

EDIT: I specify something following Ian's comment. The above calculus shows that $G$ is indeed harmonic where $G$ is well defined (*i.e.* when $x\neq0$ and $y\neq0$). The fact is there was an ambiguity in the OP's question to me. I answered to the question "what the scalar laplacian is?" and supposed $G$ well defined to do it.
Now, if the question was computing the integral on the disk, what I said is not correct (see comments).

Comment: Ah well that makes sense. Thank you very much.  Would the flux integral of the 2-D gradient also be 0? That is $\int{\Delta{G}}\cdot{\vec{n}}dA$

Comment: If $\Delta G$ is identically zero as above, the answer is yes. But your last formula says that this time $\Delta G$ is a vector, so $G$ must take its value in $\mathbb{R}^2$ here. If you want more detail, please precise the function $G$.

Comment: There is a very important error in this answer: $G$ is *not* harmonic on the disk. It has zero Laplacian at every point *except zero*, where its Laplacian in the distributional sense is a multiple of the Dirac delta and its Laplacian in the pointwise sense doesn't exist. (Indeed, usually we see this function emerge when we attempt to find the fundamental solution to the Laplace equation in two dimensions.)

Comment: (Cont.) Consequently the flux integral $\int \nabla G \cdot n dA$ is *not* zero, as is actually quite easy to see, since the gradient and the normal are both outward radial vectors. So -1 for now; I will retract this when the error is corrected.

Comment: @FofX Please note my previous comment to avoid any confusion. Also note that the problem you were being asked about may have been to calculate the integral in the distributional sense. This can be done without formal appeal to distribution theory by using the divergence theorem (since the Laplacian is the divergence of the gradient).

Comment: @Ian : You're right, what I wrote is only correct in the pointwise sense, where indeed I supposed well defined $G$ to compute the partial derivatives (in the usual sense). I gave this answer especially to explain what the laplacian was for a real valued function, because FofX seemed to be confused with it. As for the integral $\int\Delta.\overrightarrow{n}\mathrm{d}A$, you're agree that it is not well defined as $\Delta G$ is not a vector... So as I wrote in comment, if the question was computing this integral rather than understanding what the scalar laplacian is, then I let FofX specify it.